# How do i make a second field validate if the first field comes back valid with jQuery validation plugn?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have two fields that are somewhat co-dependent on each other. If these two fields, barname and address exists already in the database, then it should return as invalid.

The problem is that I have used the remote feature with a data function to validate both fields when one is changed. However, if an error is generated and then later corrected with one of the fields, the error message is only removed for the field that was most recently changed.

Is there a way to force the second field to validate as well if the first one comes back as valid?

```
$('#addbarform').validate({
    rules: {
        barname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            remote: {
                url: "2011-content/includes/checkbarname.php",
                data: {
                    address: function() {
                        return $('#address').val();
                    },
                    barname: function() {
                        return $('#barname').val();

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        address: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: "2011-content/includes/checkbarname.php",
                data: {
                    barname: function() {
                        return $('#barname').val();

                    },
                    address: function() {
                        return $('#address').val();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        barname: {
            remote: 'This bar name already exists at this address.'
        },
        address: {
            remote: 'This bar name already exists at this address.'
        }
    }
});
```

I've attempted to solve it using the following code but it does not work.

```
$('#barname').blur(function () {
    if ($('#barname').is(".valid") && ($('#address').is(".error"))) {
        $("#address").valid();
    }
});

$('#address').blur(function () {
    if ($('#barname').is(".error") && ($('#address').is(".valid"))) {
        $("#barname").valid();
    }
});
```